# How can I collect and output all attributes of all executed ShortCodes?

Tags: shortcode, hooks, actions

I would like to collect all attributes of the shortcodes that are stored in a page in the ShortCodes and then output them all.
I do these in a Plugin.

1.) Set a global Variable in init.php ==> $allShortcodeAtts = array();

2.) store atts in the global variable in the hook

```
function wpdocs_bartag_func( $atts ) {
 $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'foo' => 'no foo',
    'baz' => 'default baz'
 ), $atts, 'bartag' );
 global $allShortcodeAtts;
 $allShortcodeAtts[] = $atts;

 /* do other stuff */
 
 return "foo = {$atts['foo']}";
}

function register_shortcodes() {
   add_shortcode ( 'bartag', 'wpdocs_bartag_func' );
}
add_action ( 'init', 'register_shortcodes', 10 );
```

3.) Deposit shortcode in post_content => [bartag foo="bar1"] [bartag foo="bar2"]

4.) output all varaibles of the shortcodes

```
function after_register_shortcodes(){
 global $allShortcodeAtts;

 var_dump($allShortcodeAtts);
}
add_action ( 'init', 'after_register_shortcodes', 999 );
```

no attributes are stored in the global variables. I do not understand why?

Comment: The `init` hook happens before WP has fetched posts, but shortcodes only run when they're rendered, so the order is all wrong

Comment: i understand, thats wrong. So many thanks...

Comment: It now works wonderfully in the frontend. In the backend unfortunately not yet. There I execute the shortcodes with do_shortcode(). Which hook can I use in the backend after do_shortcode()?

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires this? It's quite an unusual thing to be doing, some context will help

Comment: Thank you Tom.
With the shortcode I generate different tables with different columns. In the attributes of the shortcode are the columns that are displayed. So far I generate the data of the tables for each shortcode. To store the data in a query, I need all columns of all tables. Therefore the collecting of these data, for the times query of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Used shorcodes can be retrived only if they are added in post content (or any content saved in db). They can not be retrived if hardcoded in template files (TBH, they can, but that's not the issue here). This code can help you to get the shortcodes used in a post content.

```
function wpse387291_get_shortcodes() {
    global $post;
    
    $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();
    
    if (   preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches ) {
        //$matches will hold the shortcodes if any
        echo '<pre>' . print_r( $matches, true ) . '</pre>';
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'wpse387291_get_shortcodes' );
```

You can use any hook that runs after `wp`.

Comment: It now works wonderfully in the frontend. In the backend unfortunately not yet. There I execute the shortcodes with do_shortcode(). Which hook can I use in the backend after do_shortcode()?

Comment: @Severin Using `do_shortcode()` mostly means you are printing it directly in HTML. There nothing (at least I know of) can be done.

Comment: I have tested many admin_* hooks for the backend from [all wp hooks](http://rachievee.com/the-wordpress-hooks-firing-sequence/) and none fire after do_shortcode(). I will have to look for another solution. Thank you for helping.